# vue3 vuetifyjs v-color-picker - How to use input event

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, color-picker

I'm new in vue3 and using v-color-picker provided by vuetify.js. My goal is that a method is executed when an input event ("new color selected") happens:

```
<v-color-picker 
  mode="hexa"
  v-model="background_color" 
  @input="handleChangedColor"
></v-color-picker>
```

...

```
methods: {
  handleChangedColor() {
    console.log("New color selected")
  }
},
```

However, the method handleChangedColor is never triggered. I would be very happy if someone could give me a hint about what I'm doing wrong!

Storing the selectedColor in the variable background_color is working correctly.
The input event is described here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-color-picker/#props

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You've linked the Vuetify 2 documentation, but since you're using Vue 3 I assume you're also using Vuetify 3.  Since Vuetify 3.0 the latest documentation is now at https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-color-picker/#events

You'll find the new v-color-picker event to listen to is `update:modelValue`

```html
<v-color-picker 
  mode="hexa"
  v-model="background_color" 
  @update:modelValue="handleChangedColor"
></v-color-picker>
```

```js
handleChangedColor(color) {
  console.log("New color selected: ", color);
}
```